# how to get selected dropdown item in php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I want selected item from "list_cust_name" in php variable to get the value in another dropdown "list_cust_city" through that sql query by passing that php variable in WHERE clause..Here is my code..Please help me..

```
<td width="228">
    <label style="color:#000">Name </label>
    <?php
        $query_name = "SELECT DISTINCT cust_name FROM customer_db ORDER BY cust_name"; //Write a query
        $data_name = mysql_query($query_name);  //Execute the query
    ?>
    <select id="list_cust_name" name="list_cust_name">
        <?php
            while($fetch_options_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_name)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
        ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td width="250"> 
    <label style="color:#000">City </label>
    <?php
        $query_city = "SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db ORDER BY cust_city"; //Write a query
        $data_city = mysql_query($query_city);  //Execute the query
    ?>
    <select id="list_cust_city" name="list_cust_city">
        <?php
            while($fetch_options_city = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_city)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
        ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $fetch_options_city['cust_city']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options_city['cust_city']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: can't get your actual problem...

Comment: you want page refresh here ? or @Jokey suggested you need ajax here to achieve this

Comment: no not refresh if i select the list_cust_name then the list_cust_city will automaticly appear the options

Answer (score 0):

You need an [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call for this.

First include `JQuery` script to your page inside `<head>` tag like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you need an event listener for onchange of your first dropdown list like the following:

```
<script>
$('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'city.php',
        data:{cust_name:$( this ).val()},
        success: function( data ){
            $('#list_cust_city').html( data );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

put the above script below your `<body>` tag.

Now you want to create a page named `city.php` as given in above ajax call. You can decide the name as you wish.

Then in that page you can get the passed value `cust_name` and you can execute query with that. The new dropdown options can generate as follows.

**city.php**

```
<?php
    $cust_name=$_GET['cust_name'];      //passed value of cust_name
    $query_city = "your query with the cust_name"; //Write a query
    $data_city = mysql_query($query_city);  //Execute the query
    while($fetch_options_city = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_city)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
    ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $fetch_options_city['cust_city']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options_city['cust_city']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }   
?>
```

After the completion of this script the datas are passed back to the AJAX call and it is placed inside the second dropdown as per our code. Try it out

Comment: After creating city.php should i write code for second dropdown in y ain page??

Comment: Yes...you need to write second dropdown code in main page...just add `<select id="list_cust_city" name="list_cust_city">`...otherwise jquery can't find the element with id `#list_cust_city`

Answer (score 0):

As like Jokey said, u need to perform ajax here...

Upto Selecting customer name there is no problem.

U have to capture the change event of `list_cust_name` in a jquery(ajax) like this

JS File:

```
$('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
    var cust_name = $('#list_cust_name').val();
    $.post( 
             "./php/getCityNames.php",
             { cust_name: cust_name },
             function(data) {
                $('#list_cust_city').html(data);
             }

          );
 });
```

The PHP File (named getCityNames.php):

```
<?php
$cust_name =  $_POST["cust_name"];  //getting the customer name sent from JS file
$query_city = "SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db WHERE cust_name = '$cust_name' ORDER BY cust_city"; //added where as per your requirement
    $data_city = mysql_query($query_city);  //Execute the query

foreach($categories as $category){  //Its my style
        echo "<option>";
        echo $data_city['cust_city'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
```